# Discord bot not sending message on member joined?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to the annoucements channel when members join. This works if I don't use `welcomeChannel` as a const and define it inside the function, but I don't want to do that.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login('*****************************************');

const welcomeChannel = bot.channels.get("name", "annoucements") // also tried .find here

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    if (welcomeChannel) {
        welcomeChannel.send(member + ', welcome to the server.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? If so, could you accept the answer that helped you so that the thread is "closed"?

Answer (score 1):

The login method of discord.js is async, meaning that when you define that constant, the bot hasn't logged in yet. If the bot isn't logged in, it can't find any channels. Either keep the constant defined locally or make it a global `let` and assign it when the ready event is emitted by the client object.

Comment: Is there a way I can `await` on the login? Before continuing.

Comment: Yes, you can use `await` on login but only from an `async function`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that: you can't `await client.login()` since it would be top-level, and you can't redefine a constant.
The only way you can keep using that value as a constant is by putting all the rest of your code inside the `ready` event so that you don't have to change its value.
It would be way easier if you didn't use constants.

Also, you have to use `guild.channels.find('name', 'channel_name')`, since `.get()` only works with IDs